# How to serve static files with capybara and cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, acceptance-testing

I want to run acceptance tests for an rss feed reader and I need an URL to an atom or rss feed. Ive got a small file which contains my sample atom/rss and i want to access it from a locally running webserver.

Basically i want to add something like this to my feed url input field:

```
http://localhost:8080/feed1.atom.xml
```

How do I serve my example file under that url?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with a static file server, e.g. a Python one is nice and fast:

```
→ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8080 ...
```

You need to copy a file at feed1.atom.xml at the location where you start up the static file server.

Comment: I thought of the same ;D but that would require users that run the suite to also install python which is a bit overkill :)